# Búsqueda de palabras múltiples en un archivo con notepad++

Tags: notepad++

yo necesito buscar en archivos con Notepad++ y que me devuelva solo aquellos archivos que contengan dos o más palabras. He probado expresiones regulares como:

"word1|word2"

Pero no me sirve porque encuentra aquellos archivos que tienen tanto la palabra word1 sola, word2 sola y word1 y word2 (ambas).

Yo necesito solo aquellos archivos que contienen las dos palabras. No me sirven los archivos que contienen 1 de las 2 palabras.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
\bpalabra1\b[\s\S]*\bpalabra2\b
```

Explicado:

```
\b        # Límite de palabra (para no encontrar 'paro' en 'amparo', por ejemplo)
palabra1  # La primera palabra a buscar
[\s\S]*   # Cualquier caracter repetido 0 o más veces
palabra2  # La segunda palabra
\b        # Límite de palabra (para no encontrar 'pepe' en 'peperoni', por ejemplo)
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/FZNY83/1/).